# Reflection for F# units of measure

Tags: c#, reflection, f#

Support for reflection has been currently added into F#, but it is not working for measure types. Is it possible to use reflection in F# for measure types?
I've read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919231247/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewkennedy/archive/2008/09/02/units-of-measure-in-f-part-two-unit-conversions.aspx). It was for 2008, but if you check some code like bellow in ildasm you cannot see anything about `Units of Measure`.

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.net

[<Measure>] type m
[<Measure>] type cm
 
let CalculateVelocity(length:float<m> ,time:float<cm>) =
    length / time
```

The ildasm output:

```
.method public static float64  CalculateVelocity(float64 length,
                                                 float64 time) cil managed
{
  // Code size       5 (0x5)
  .maxstack  4
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldarg.1
  IL_0003:  div
  IL_0004:  ret
} // end of method Program::CalculateVelocity
```

So there are somethings that cannot be reflected in F#. Is it true or not?
see the comment : Units actually don't get seen at all by the CLR ... in the article.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others already pointed out, when you need to get some information about compiled F# types, you can use standard .NET reflection (`System.Reflection`) and F# reflection which provides information about discriminated unions, records, etc. (`Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection`).

Unfortunatelly, information about *units of measure* cannot be accessed using any of these two APIs, because they are checked only during the compilation and do not actually exist at runtime (they cannot be represented in the CLR in any way). This means that you'll never be able to find out whether e.g. a boxed floating point value has some unit of measure...

You can get *some* information about units of measure using `Metadata` namespace from F# PowerPack. For example, the following prints that `foo` is a unit:

```
namespace App
open System.Reflection
open Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata

[<Measure>] 
type foo

module Main = 
  let asm = FSharpAssembly.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
  for ent in asm.Entities do
    if ent.IsMeasure then
      printfn "%s is measure" ent.DisplayName
```

This reads some binary metadata that the compiler stores  in compiled files (so that you can see units when you reference other F# libraries), so you should be able to see informaiton about public API of F# libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Units of Measure is just a compile-time thing, it doesn't exist in the assembly/CLR.

From [part one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andrewkennedy/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units):

> Units-of-measure are not just handy
> comments-on-constants: they are there
> in the types of values, and, what's
> more, the F# compiler knows the rules
> of units.

Comment: They do exist in the assembly, but they're encoded in a resource rather than in members' signatures.  See Tomas's answer for a demonstration that units can be recovered at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

> #### .NET and F# Reflection
>
> The F# library also extends the .NET `System.Reflection` to give additional information about F# data types

[Source](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-iv-lang.aspx)

Comment: @SaeedAlg - the bit about reflection starts half way down the page.