# What is the format placeholder for numbers (values) with units in F#?

Tags: f#

How do I print out a number with a unit? Shall I use "%A" or shall I strip the unit first? MSDN doesn't say anything: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee370560.aspx

```
[<Measure>] type hr
let a = 10<hr>

printf "%d" a // <-- doesn't compile: Unit of measure 'hr' doesn't match the unit of measure '1'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you print the resulting units using units of measure in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359767/how-do-you-print-the-resulting-units-using-units-of-measure-in-f)

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate. The other question is about how to print out the actual unit part of the unit of measure. This is about getting anything to print out at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like strong typing for your `hr` unit of measure you could use "%a".

`printf "%a"` expects a function where the first parameter is a `TextWriter` and the second is any value you specify. Using this would allow you to require `int<hr>` as the second argument which will provide type checking at compile time.

Have a look at the code below:

```
open System.IO

[<Measure>] type hr

let printHours (tw:TextWriter) (hours:int<hr>) =
    tw.Write("{0} hour(s)", hours)
```

The example in your question would be written as:

```
let a = 10<hr>
printf "%a" printHours a
```

This will print **10 hour(s)** to the console.

If you pass in a value that does not have an `hr` unit, you will get a lovely error:

```
printf "%a" printHours 10;;

printf "%a" printHours 10;;
-----------------------^^

error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int<hr>    
but here has type
    int
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do either `printf "%O hour(s)" a` or else `int a |> printf "%i hour(s)"`. One is type-safe, and one is short.