# How to generalise printing measure

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I'm dealing with fees in some currency. My question is about implementing the currency with a unit of measurement, which seems more "natural" than a discriminated union `type Currency = EUR | JPN | USD`.

```ml
type [<Measure>] EUR
type [<Measure>] JPN
type [<Measure>] USD
```

In a generic manner, we can identify *no fees*, for instance with an active pattern:

```ml
let (|NoFees|SomeFees|) (fees: decimal<_>) =
    if fees = 0m<_> then NoFees else SomeFees
```

But how to print the currency?

```ml
let printFeesAcceptanceMessage fees =
    match fees with
    | NoFees -> ()
    | SomeFees -> printfn $"I accept the fees of {fees} ???" //  How to print the currency ❓
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359767/how-do-you-print-the-resulting-units-using-units-of-measure-in-f

Comment: @nilekirk: thank you for your answer. I close the question cause duplicated the one you mentioned.