# How to get the list of F# type abbreviations via reflection?

Tags: reflection, f#, units-of-measurement

How can I get a list of the F# type abbreviations via reflection? `Assembly.GetTypes` doesn't return them, and I don't see anything for that in `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection`. I'm trying to get all the type abbreviations in `` Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI.Unit`Names `` and `Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI.UnitSymbols`

Comment: This is actually possible - see Tomas' answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005474/why-can-not-use-reflection-in-f